# What is this needle called?

Tags: tool-identification

I have this old needle, that I found in a box at a car boot sale and cleaned for rust, and I wonder what it is called? It is ~12cm (5") long, and the eye is large enough that I can use it to sew with something like baling twine, and it has turned out to be very good for an ancient technique called 'nålebinding' (ie. 'needle binding' translated) with thick yarn. The fact that it is somewhat flattened and bent at the sharp end is actually a helpful feature, in my opinion. I'd like to buy some more in different sizes - but what are they called?

[image]

Comment: Possibly related: [Why are needles designed for sewing thick canvas or heavy leather three-edged?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/10450/why-are-needles-designed-for-sewing-thick-canvas-or-heavy-leather-three-edged)

Comment: These are also used for closing sacks and wool bales with baling twine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks a lot like an old sail/sailing/sailor's/sail maker's needle:

| [image] |
| --- |
| "*A rare and interesting Welsh Sailors or Sail Makers tool kit. A full set of sail makers needles, string and large for penetrating the heavy canvas along with two net making/repairing tools. All houses in an original case.*" The length of the case is 19 cm. <sup>[source](https://www.antiques-atlas.com/antique/19thc_welsh_sail_makers_tools_sailors_needles__/as223a891)</sup> |

Comment: I think that is the answer! Thanks!

Comment: Being familiar with rope splicing, this is absolutely the right answer.

Answer (score 6):

It could be a leather working needle:

[image]
<sup>[source](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/vintage-large-leather-working-needles-543376326)</sup>

The ones in this picture are 7"/17.8 cm, but are described as 'large'.

Comment: These do have the shape, but I think the tips are triangular - mine only has two edges, which aren't sharp.